# I want to copy a page text in a variable

Tags: php

I want to copy a page text in a variable. I use file_get_contents method but it don't work for my address for example my address is :

http://ir93.com
but this code not show the text of this page:

```
$filename='http://www.bankmellat.ir/3/Default/94/1/Default/2/875/1/201.aspx?itemid=201';
$homepage =  file_get_contents($filename , false);
echo ($homepage);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change allow_url_fopen to 1 in your php.ini.